# Django filters and serializers. Filter model one-to-many nested values

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework

I know how to apply filter to viewset for current model by nested values and return all data concerning to this foreign key.

And that's okay if I have one-to-one relation. But I have one-to-many relation. So I don't know how to filter also these "many values".

Now I have smth like this.

**filters.py**:

```
class VersionFilter(FilterSet):
    tool = CharFilter(method='tool_filter')

    def tool_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        queryset = queryset.filter(changes__tool=value).distinct()
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = ('tool')
```

**serializers.py**:

```
class ChangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Change
        fields = ('tool', 'date', 'type', 'title', 'description')


class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    changes = ChangeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = ('date', 'version', 'changes')
```

**viewsets.py**:

```
class VersionViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    model = Version
    queryset = Version.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VersionSerializer
    filter_class = VersionFilter
```

**And here is the return** for url smth like `127.0.0.0/api/version?tool=General`:

```
"data": [
    {
        "date": "2017-03-21T10:25:47.848959Z",
        "version": "1.12",
        "changes": [
            {
                "tool": "General",
                "date": "2017-03-21T10:26:22.838785Z",
                "type": "Fix",
                "title": "dfa",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "tool": "General",
                "date": "2017-03-21T10:26:08.379112Z",
                "type": "Fix",
                "title": "dasf",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-03-21T10:33:43Z",
        "version": "1.01.12",
        "changes": [
            {
                "tool": "General",
                "date": "2017-03-21T10:44:35.143232Z",
                "type": "Improvement",
                "title": "qw",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "tool": "Costs",
                "date": "2017-03-21T10:34:12.482258Z",
                "type": "Fix",
                "title": "dfaasss",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So, versions were filtered by tool "General" (it's not visible here, but one version is out). But due to serializer, tool "Costs" is still in the query (and I want it to be removed).

**How can I achieve it?**

Comment: did you try `Version.objects.exclude(somequery)`

Answer (score 0):

```
class VersionFilter(FilterSet):
    tool = CharFilter(method='tool_filter')

    def tool_filter(self, request, queryset):
        # get all values matching query params
        tool = request.GET.get('tool')
        date = request.GET.get('date')
        type = request.GET.get('type')
        title = request.GET.get('title')
        description = request.GET.get('description')

        data = {
            "tool": tool,
            "date": date,
            "type": type,
            "title": title,
            "description": description
        }

        arguments = {}
        # filter out values that evaluate to false e.g. None, ''
        for k, v in data.items():
            if v:
                arguments[k] = v

        # run query 
        queryset = queryset.objects.filter(**arguments)
        return queryset
```

The code is untested but it is very useful if you want to return filters in query params like containing localhost:8000`/?param1=value1&param2=value2` etc.

Comment: I don't have `request` variable in `tool_filter` function. What to you mean under it?

Comment: oh i see what you mean. Do you get error if you add a `request` parameter just after self otherwise best use the code in a serializer method